# How to decouple actions from security checks?

Tags: architecture

In my application, the user can perform lots of various actions, e.g. (the book/library examples are just to make it clearer; the actions in my application are much more complex):

- Rent a book
- Read a book
- Write a book
- Move a book
- Lookup a book
- ...

My application also contains some security checks that prevent some of these actions.
These checks are not directly related to the actions, but represent concepts separately from the actions, e.g.:

- Allowed to open a book or not
- Allowed to make modifications or not
- Allowed to see the existance of a book or not

Currently, the different actions (renting, reading, ...) contain code like this:

```
void readBook (Book &book)
   {
   if (!checkSecurity (book, OPENBOOK|SEEBOOK)) return;
   ...
   }

void writeBook (Book &book)
   {
   if (!checkSecurity (book, MODIFYBOOK)) return;
   ...
   }
```

This approach makes it very hard to add new types of security checks in a dynamic way.  E.g. a dynamic plugin might add additional security checks.

The solution I am currently working on is that the different actions call an interface that looks like this:

```
class ISecurityChecker
   {
   public:
      bool isReadBookAllowed() const = 0;
      bool isWriteBookAllowed() const = 0;
      ...
   };
```

A composite class then implements this interface.  Other implementations of this interface can be added to the composite.  That way, a plugin or a dynamic part of the application can simply add new security checks when needed.

There are also some disadvantages to this approach.  The main problem is that the interface becomes very big.  I am going to see if I can merge some of the interface methods (because they basically perform the same or similar action), but it's not sure whether this will be possible.

Any other alternatives to improve the decoupling?  Or suggestions on how to improve this design?

Comment: Is there something (or a limited set of thing) that acts like a "gateway": i.e. when the user does something it always goes via some route? For instance, in some apps a user action becomes a http request, and therefore one might apply checks and rules at a single choke-point that looks at the http requests. Do you have something similar?

Comment: @Darius.  The application is a large simulation application that executes everything on the desktop (because of lots of mathematical calculations that need all of the data).  So no central http gateway.  What I now try to add is a central function/class/interface/framework that performs the necessary checks (without being a gateway itself), but the problem is that I end up with a big matrix (N actions x M possible security checks) and I am trying to see what the best approach is: either perform the M checks for each action, or have every check have logic to check each of the N actions.

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible changes I can suggest ... and one comment.

**Firstly**, push your primitive checks down the chain as far as possible. Throw exceptions to communicate authorization errors.

```
void readBook (Book &book)
{
   // readbook doesn't need to perform any checks of it's own.
   // the more primitive actions will scream and yell if the user
   // isn't allowed to perform sub-action X.

   openBook(book);
   BookData d = getBookData(book);

   // etc.
}

void openBook (Book &book)
{
  if (!checkSecurity (book, OPENBOOK))
    throw new SecurityException("User X is not allowed to open this book!");

  // etc.
}

BookData getBookData (Book &book)
{
  if (!checkSecurity (book, SEEBOOK))
    throw new SecurityException("User X is not allowed to read this book's data!");

  // etc.
}
```

**Secondly**, map your security actions to *actual actions*. You can even do this in data, if you like. For instance ...

```
class Security {

  // this check get tricky.
  // if an "real action" isn't listed anywhere, does the user have implicit permission?
  // (i'm assuming not, for this example.)
  public static Check(String realAction, Boolean requireAll = true) {
    Int32 required = 0;
    Int32 userHas = 0;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, List<String>> pair in Actions) {
      if (pair.Value.Contains(realAction))
      {
        required++;
        if (Security.CurrentUser.Actions.Contains(pair.Key))
        {
          userHas++;
        }
      }
    }

    if (requireAll)
    {
      return userHas > 0 && userHas == required;
    }
    else
    {
      return userHas > 0;
    }
  }

  // hardcoded here, but easily populated from a database or config file
  public static Dictionary<String, List<String>> Actions {
    {"OpenBook", new List<String>() { "readBook", "writeBook" }},
    {"SeeBook", new List<String>() { "readBook", "writeBook" }}
  }

}

void readBook(Book &book) {
  if (!Security.Check("readBook")) return false;
  // etc.
}
```

The `Check()` method here takes in a `requireAll` parameter, but the mappings themselves could just as easily be updated to "insist" or "prefer" on being present for their implied "real actions."

**And my comment**: Don't over-detail your security. Some security rules imply other rules which may be meaningless on their own. For instance, `READBOOK` and `WRITEBOOK` both imply an ability to `OPENBOOK`, and `OPENBOOK` is probably meaningless on its own. And while it may seem silly for a user to be able to `OPENBOOK` or `WRITEBOOK` without things like `SEEBOOKCOVER` and `SEEBOOKINSEARCHRESULTS` or whatever, I'd suggest that the only relevant permission at book reading time is `READBOOK`.

Comment: Your second approach looks what I am currently experimenting with, adding calls to a central check interface, with the action as argument.  However, instead of using strings I use separate methods which can then be implemented by security checkers (or not if they don't care about the action).  Your approach is interesting because you define the matrix explicitly at startup of the application by registering the combinations of actions and security checks.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Command-Query Separation (CQS) approach. The general idea is to define a command class like this:

```
public class Command
{
    public Command(Action<object> act, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
    {
        this.act = act;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    private Action<object> act;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;
    public void Execute()
    {
        if (CanExecute())
        {
            act(this);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Command cannot be executed");
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        if (this.canExecute != null)
        {
            return this.canExecute(this);
        }
        else return true;
    }
}
```

Then in the page, you use `Command.Execute()` instead of regular `book.Write` / `book.Print`, etc.

The usage:

```
Command readBookCommand = new Command(
    k =>
    {
        book.Read();
    },
    l =>
    {
        CanReadBook();
    }
);
readBookCommand.Execute();
```

There may be better implementation of CQS out there. This is just a simple illustration.